# More memory for ESP32 when using bluetooth, SPIFFS and WiFi

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, esp8266, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I'm working on a project that will have SPIFFS, Bluetooth and WiFi libraries. The program is all set so the librarys don't interfere in the communication, since Bluetooth can't work when WiFi is set.
 But I'm getting the following problem when I attempt to add a command line from the library `https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32`, this library is responsable of making connection to firestore database:

```
text section exceeds available space in boardSketch uses 1517102 bytes (115%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.

Global variables use 63300 bytes (19%) of dynamic memory, leaving 264380 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
Sketch too big; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing it.
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.
```

I only get this error when adding this piece of code:

```
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
```

I'm using arduino ide to work with esp32, but I have esp-idf in case it helps solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've reached the limit of the partition size for your application. I don't know how Arduino configures the ESP IDF partitions, but you should be able to change them however you want. See the [documetation on partitions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html)